# bootstrap rowspan firefox bug

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

**Browser:** Only firefox, Chrome is OK
**OS:** Linux, Windows (OSX not tested)

**example:**

```
        <tr class="day-row">
            <td class="center" rowspan="4">1</td>
            <td class="center" rowspan="2">projekt</td>
            <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
            <td>None</td>
            <td>0.8</td>
            <td class="center" rowspan="4">1.6</td>
            <td class="center" rowspan="4"></td>
            <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="day-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a>Nový</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="day-row">
            <td class="center" rowspan="2">frontend</td>
            <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
            <td>None</td>
            <td>0.8</td>
            <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="day-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a>Nový</a></td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="day-row">
            <td class="center" rowspan="4">2</td>
            <td class="center" rowspan="2">projekt</td>
            <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
            <td>None</td>
            <td>0.8</td>
            <td class="center" rowspan="4">HERE IS BORDER-BOTTOM SHOWN</td>
            <td class="center" rowspan="4"></td>
            <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="day-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a>Nový</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="day-row">
            <td class="center" rowspan="2">frontend</td>
            <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
            <td>None</td>
            <td>0.8</td>
            <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="day-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a>Nový</a></td>
        </tr>


        <tr class="day-row">
            <td class="center" rowspan="4">3</td>
            <td class="center" rowspan="2">projekt</td>
            <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
            <td>None</td>
            <td>0.8</td>
            <td class="center" rowspan="4">1.6</td>
            <td class="center" rowspan="4"></td>
            <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="day-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a>Nový</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="day-row">
            <td class="center" rowspan="2">frontend</td>
            <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
            <td>None</td>
            <td>0.8</td>
            <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="day-row">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><a>Nový</a></td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fdyrs27x/1/

**description:**
There are 3 cases and in only first case the bug occurs on row starting with '2' under 6. td. There is line under the td, but the cell is expanded to four rows. It should not be there.

1. default bootstrap
2. bootstrap with td, tr -> border: 1px solid
   gray;
3. default bootsrap with 2 rows only

Does anybody know how to fixed it?

Comment: Check the Normalize.css on line no 416 comment "border-collapse: collapse;" Try to include the css locally.

Comment: yes this is the solution, thanks, if you would create answer I would accept it

Comment: If you can share css?

Comment: I commented border-collapse:collapse on two rows in dowloaded bootstrap.css and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Great, it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try**

Download the bootstrap css from below location.
    [https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css]
embed it your html/page.

Comment the below code from table definition.

```
border-collapse:collapse
```

Read more [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your outside bootstrap css

```
`table {
    border-collapse: initial !important;
}`
```

It stops the table borders collapsing into a single border.

Do not edit your bootstrap.css file.

Answer (score 0):

there is a style from bootstrap css

```
 .table > tbody > tr > td{
   padding: 8px;
   line-height: 1.42857143;
   vertical-align: top;
   border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

you need to write your code so you overwrite that. ( that is causing the problem )

so your code should be : check snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdyrs27x/3/)

```css
.table.bordered, .borderd th, .table > tbody > tr > td{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
       
       <h2>
         ERROR SHOWN
       </h2>
       <table class="table table-stripped day-list">
            <tbody>

            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">1</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">projekt</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">1.6</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4"></td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
               
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">frontend</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">2</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">projekt</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">HERE IS BORDER-BOTTOM SHOWN</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4"></td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                 <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">frontend</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">3</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">projekt</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">1.6</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4"></td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">frontend</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
               <h2>
         WITHOUT ERROR - added border to table th and td
       </h2>
       <table class="table table-stripped bordered">
            <tbody>

            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">1</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">projekt</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">1.6</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4"></td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">frontend</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">2</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">projekt</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">1.6</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4"></td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">frontend</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">3</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">projekt</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">1.6</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4"></td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">frontend</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
                       <h2>
        ALSO WITHOUT ERROR - different row counts
       </h2>
       <table class="table table-stripped">
            <tbody>

            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">1</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">projekt</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">1.6</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4"></td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">frontend</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">2</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">projekt</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4">1.6</td>
                <td class="center" rowspan="4"></td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td class="center" rowspan="2">frontend</td>
                <td>ActivityGroupName object</td>
                <td>None</td>
                <td>0.8</td>
                <td><a>Upravit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="day-row">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Nový</a></td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```